# failed to install phablet-tools on 12.04

Tags: apt, ubuntu-touch

I couldn't install phablet-tools on my 12.04 machine, I had try

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[...]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en
[...]
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install phablet-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 phablet-tools : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And my python version:

```
$dpkg -l python

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold

| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend

|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)

||/ Name           Version        Description

+++-==============-==============-============================================

ii  python         2.7.3-0ubuntu2 interactive high-level object-oriented langu
```

I don't know what's wrong, any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

First things first, try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then try to *install again*. If this fails lets try something else. The first will update the software database and the second will try to fix any broken dependencies.

If this fails you can try to install by force

```
sudo apt-get download phablet-tools
sudo dpkg -i <filename of package>
```

The file should be in the same folder you are working.

However I wouldn't recommend using the tools on a broken system, I can't tell what can happen to the devices you manage with it.

If nothing else, I am always open to re-install my entire system. No broken dependencies, no issues. Always have a partition to keep the data I need and an external hard-drive.

Answer (score 0):

### You should have completed these steps:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install phablet-tools android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
```

### What if any errors did you get, when you did?